# iOS custom share extension: load selected image

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I'm working on a share extension for my app, to be able to use it for sharing images directly from the library. I have a view controller and layout set up, but I'm struggling with getting the selected image to show in the `UIImageView` inside the view controller.

For now, my `getImage()` is as follows:

```
func getImage() {
    if let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
        if let itemProvider = inputItem.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG as String) { [unowned self] (imageData, error) in
                if let item = imageData as? Data {
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: item)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...but the image is not loading. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. Turned out I needed to do a type identifier conformance check first:

```
func getImage() {
    if let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
        if let itemProvider = inputItem.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
            // This line was missing
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeJPEG as String) { 
                itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG as String) { [unowned self] (imageData, error) in
                    if let item = imageData as? Data {
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```